# Add column between them if two columbs are the same Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a df such as

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
A 1 0 Mus_musculus
A 0 1 Mus_musculus
A 1 0 Bos_taurus
B 1 0 Mus_musculus
C 0 1 Mus_musculus
C 1 0 Mus_musculus
C 1 0 Mus_musculus
A 0 1 Mus_musculus
```

I would like to add the columns `COL2` and `COL3` between them if the columns `COL1` and `COL4` are identical only.

Ex:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
A 1 0 Mus_musculus
A 0 1 Mus_musculus
A 0 1 Mus_musculus
```

All **COL1** have `A` and all **COL4** have `Mus_musculus`

Then I add the `COL2` and `COL3` together and get only 1 row instead of 3:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
A 1 2 Mus_musculus
```

The expected final result should be :

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
A 1 2 Mus_musculus
A 1 0 Bos_taurus
B 1 0 Mus_musculus
C 2 1 Mus_musculus
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.groupby()`

```
df2 = df1.groupby(["COL1","COL4"]).agg({"COL2":"sum","COL3":"sum"}).reset_index()
```